# Filling forms with Mechanize error ( HTTP Error 400: Bad Request)

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I am trying to make a script on Python that autofills a form on this [website](https://1.shortstack.com/N9T1D2) form using Mechanize.

```
      import mechanize
      br = mechanize.Browser()
      response = br.open ("https://www.example.com")
      url = "https://www.example.com"
      br.select_form (nr=0)
      br.form ['form[first_name]'] = Name
      br.form ['form[last_name]'] = Name2
      br.form ['form[image_title]'] = tittle
      br.form ['form[email]'] = Email
      response = br.submit()
      response = browser.open ('https://www.example.com')
      print(response.read())
```

the issue is I keep running into error as mechanize can't find the name ID, :

```
  mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe typo for title, not tittle.

Comment: it is not a typo, it is variable name.

Comment: I'm afraid, I can find image_title but cannot find image_tittle in website you've linked.

Comment: I have made edits: here is the out error : " mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"